# Kotlin parse double from string

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin how to parse a double or float number from string like this:

```
var st: String? = "90 min"
```

tried to use toDoubleOrNull but always returns 0 or null.

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that the number is always at the start, then use [`split()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) with space as delimiter and from the returned list take the 1st item and parse it to `Double`:

```
val value = st!!.split(" ")[0].toDoubleOrNull()
```

If there is a case of spaces at the start or in between, use this:

```
val value = st!!.trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())[0].toDoubleOrNull()
```

And another way with [`substringBefore()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before.html):

```
val value = st!!.trim().substringBefore(" ").toDoubleOrNull()
```

Or if there is only 1 integer number in the string, remove every non numeric char with [`replace()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html):

```
val value = st!!.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "").toDoubleOrNull()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try (assuming you have only one sequence of numbers in your string).

Otherwise, check other answers

```
val inputString = "123. Test"
val regex = "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?".toRegex()
val match = regex.find(inputString)

if (match != null) {
    println("Result: " + match.value)
} else {
    println("Result: Not found")
}
```

Comment: this needs to update to match Doubles not Int only.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+") // the regex
val matcher = pattern.matcher("hello123hgj") // your string
val doubles = ArrayList<Double>() // results
while (matcher.find())
{ // for each match
  doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group())) // convert to double
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you need. If you just have to get 90 and the string is formatted always in the same way you can just

```
var string = "90 min"
var floatFromString = string.substring(0,2).toFloat()
```

but it's better to learn how to use LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Please consider how would this implementation fail if the string is one of `"9999 min"`, `"area 51"`, `"3 boys"`, `"test 123 test"`